# svg mask для лоадера

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Есть такой интересный лоадер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, должна быть картинка, svg лоадер, маска. Принцип как тут - [пример](https://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/CHgrn?editors=1000) (использование `mask`).

Пока есть набросок:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3137/2698866948_f273755a09_z.jpg?zz=1) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="loader">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <path  d="M 50 50 L 35 0 L 65 0 z" />
        </clipPath>

        <ellipse id= "MyEllipse" clip-path="url(#clip)"
                 cx="50" cy="50" rx="40" ry="40"
                 style="fill:none; stroke:#eee" stroke-width="20" />
      </defs>


      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" />
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(40 50 50)" />
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(80 50 50)" />
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(120 50 50)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(160 50 50)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(200 50 50)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(240 50 50)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(280 50 50)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(320 50 50)"/>


      <ellipse clip-path="url(#clip)"
               cx="50" cy="50" rx="40" ry="40"
               style="fill:none; stroke:black" stroke-width="20"  >
        
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate" values="0 50 50; 40 50 50; 80 50 50; 120 50 50;
                                                160 50 50; 200 50 50; 240 50 50; 280 50 50; 320 50 50; 360 50 50"  
                          dur="3s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"
                          additive="replace"
                          calcMode="discrete" fill="freeze"/>
      </ellipse> 
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант с маской**:

```css
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

svg text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg #alpha {
  fill: #666666;
}

svg #title {
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

svg #base {
  fill: black;
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
          mask: url(#mask);
}

section.intro {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/953/mision.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <svg>
   <defs>
     <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
       <!-- alpha rectangle -->
       <!-- rectángulo alfa -->
       <rect id="alpha" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
       <!-- All text that you want -->
       <!-- Coloca todo el texto que necesites -->       
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

          <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip">
              <path  d="M 50 50 L 35 0 L 65 0 z" />
            </clipPath>

            <ellipse id= "MyEllipse" clip-path="url(#clip)"
                     cx="50" cy="50" rx="40" ry="40"
                     style="fill:none; stroke:#999" stroke-width="20" />
          </defs>

          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" />
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(40 50 50)" />
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(80 50 50)" />
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(120 50 50)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(160 50 50)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(200 50 50)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(240 50 50)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(280 50 50)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#MyEllipse" transform="rotate(320 50 50)"/>


          <ellipse clip-path="url(#clip)"
                   cx="50" cy="50" rx="40" ry="40"
                   style="fill:none; stroke:black" stroke-width="20"  >

            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                              type="rotate" values="0 50 50; 40 50 50; 80 50 50; 120 50 50;
                                                    160 50 50; 200 50 50; 240 50 50; 280 50 50; 320 50 50; 360 50 50"  
                              dur="3s"
                              repeatCount="indefinite"
                              additive="replace"
                              calcMode="discrete" fill="freeze"/>
          </ellipse> 
        </svg>
     </mask>
    </defs>
    <!-- Apply color here! -->
    <!-- Color aquí -->
    <rect id="base" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<section class="intro"></section>
```

[На codepen.](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/VyYLxB?editors=1100)

Но проблема, что svg внутри svg (думаю это совсем не валидно), и анимация не совсем такая, когда активная секция появляется предыдущая должна быть на половину видимой.

**Вопрос:** как можно реализовать такой лоадер (как на картинке), можно ли правильно применить к существующему `svg` маску?

Comment: @Классный вопрос! Попробую порешать. Подождёшь?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, не спешу)

Comment: @Alexandr_T,  вчера, когда вопрос прочитал, первая мысль, которая была, когда еще не видел твоего коммента - "Интересно, а Alexandr_T, этот вопрос видел ?" А ты тут как тут))))...

Comment: @Air Вопросов по SVG в целом, стало очень мало в последнее время, а тут настоящий вопрос, есть над чем подумать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Загрузчик сделал в два раза больше, чем было в вопросе. Иначе смысла нет от прозрачности,- ничего не было видно.  В случае необходимости можно поменять на 
 `max-width: 200px;`
Позиционирование ещё нужно доработать.

Вся соль анимации - использование `stroke-dasharray` совместно с `stroke-dashoffset`. 
Один круг- шаблон. Второй круг- бегунок по шаблону.

```css
.box { 

width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hopXQ.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
 
 max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="loader">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="50 50 400 400"  >
<circle cx="250" cy="250" r="100" style="stroke:black; fill:none; stroke-opacity:0.3; stroke-width:50; stroke-dasharray:70 8.5;" /> 

<circle transform="rotate(-90 250 250)" cx="250" cy="250" r="100" style="stroke:dodgerblue; fill:none; stroke-opacity:0.4; stroke-width:50;
 stroke-dasharray:70 558; stroke-dashoffset: 558" >
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-78.5;-157;-235.5;-314;-392.5;-471;-549.5" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="discrete" fill="freeze" />
  </circle>
 
      
   </svg>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: и не то) суть же в том, что изображение находится под маской, а в месте лоадера просвечивается и четко видно изображение, как в примере с text mask

Comment: @А тут не видно? :)

Comment: Так а тут наоборот все, просто у лоадера прозрачность, а голубой цвет по кругу анимируется

Comment: @С маской с ходу не получается, в статике проще с маской, как в твоем примере, а вот в динамике проблемы, но порешаю ещё с маской

Comment: Добавила в вопрос вариант с тем что получилось с маской) но с жуткими костылями

Comment: @Вот-вот и у меня именно такие варианты были, даже показывать не стал, дело в том что маска перекрывает изображение и нужны костыли, чтобы засунуть обратно изображение :-) А что решение самого лоадера не заценила - всего две команды SVG? а не 20 строк